# Generating new table in Power BI dynamically from another table

Tags: datatable, powerbi, expression, dax

I am working with Power BI in which I have a list of names in a particular column which has a date attached to each. I need to modify this table to create extra rows that create a further two dates for each name, so each name has 3 rows attached to it, the original, the day before, and the day afterwards.

For example if I had

```
Person  |  Date
Luke    |  2021-06-01
Adam    |  2021-05-12
Ben     |  2021-04-28
```

This would be modified to be

```
Person  |  Date
Luke    |  2021-05-31
Luke    |  2021-06-01
Luke    |  2021-06-02
Adam    |  2021-05-11
Adam    |  2021-05-12
Adam    |  2021-05-13
Ben     |  2021-04-27
Ben     |  2021-04-28
Ben     |  2021-04-29
```

The dataset I have is many thousands of names. Does anyone know how to create the output in a new table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve that is to add couple of custom columns, named `PrevDate` and `NextDate` for example, as follows:

[image]

and

[image]

This will give you all 3 dates per person, but in 3 separate columns:

[image]

To combine them into a single column, select all date columns and click `Transform` -> `Unpivot Columns`:

[image]

If you want, you can delete `Attribute` column, if it is not needed.